# Dynamically Load javascript files inside file:/// in android Webkit

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I need to dynamically load a javascript file in my android webkit .I am using phonegap.The see that I am not able to use $.getScript for internal files with file:///android_assets/www/js.How do I load the js file .please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just load the file using XHR then do an eval on the contents. The eval should be safe considering it is your code you are loading. Here is an example where I use XHR to load a JSON file.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/01/on-eleventh-day-of-phonegapping.html

If you change JSON.parse() to eval() you should get the behaviour you want.

Comment: The problem is the javascript needs to be included inside my injected html (loaded using jquery load()).Since including the scripts inside injected html dint work,i resorted to $.getScript inside my load callback like $("#id").load("some.html",function(){$.getScript("js")}).

Comment: The other other nasty thing about the eval suggestion is that debugging is incredibly painful.  Stack traces will have function names, but not the files they're defined in.